# Javascript error if not in Form section

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this javascript:

```
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ageProb() {
            var DatePicker1 = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>");
            DatePicker1.get_dateInput()._textBoxElement.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            DatePicker1.get_dateInput().focus();
        }
</script>
```

When I run the code I get this error:**"Impossible to modify the Controls collection because the control contains code blocks  (like <% ... %>)"**

If I move the Javascript into the Form section (I found this advice googling around) then the error does not occurs but I am under the impression that the function does not get the call:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ageProb", "ageProb();", true);
```

I do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this and it will work, but you should put it in the body:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel runat="server">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function ageProb() {
                    var DatePicker1 = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>");
                DatePicker1.get_dateInput()._textBoxElement.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                DatePicker1.get_dateInput().focus();
            }
            </script>
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, basically in the Form section but in a Panel. No errors but the function does not get the call! Do you see any problem in the code that calls the function?

Comment: @FeliceM Maybe because you call it before you declare it... see browser console for any error...

Comment: Thanks, it works, the function gets called. The problem is that the desired effect on the radpicker does not show but this is a different topic. Thanks